# 3 Column Responsive CSS (Ordering Contents Positions)

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, stylesheet

Im wondering is there any way to order the contents position when the screen size is reduced to 480 or lower. What i mean is in col 3 i will have the name, number & address etc, in column 2 i will have social stuff and col 1 i will have an image. I would like to have the name and address stack up first, then the image, then the social icons. The order would be 3,1,2. Im trying to keep it responsive.

**CSS:**

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
} 

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GRID OF THREE           ============================================================================= */


.span_3_of_3 {
width: 100%; 
}

.span_2_of_3 {
width: 66.1%; 
}

.span_1_of_3 {
width: 32.2%; 
}


 /*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%; 
}
.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 100%; 
}
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section group">
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
This is column 1
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
This is column 2
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
This is column 3
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

It would be more efficient to optimize your source order for mobile and use metadept's solution for reordering the columns for desktop.

However, if the source order cannot be modified for whatever reason or you do not know the widths of the elements you wish to reorder, then you need Flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/4KUUt/3/

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
/* line 5, ../sass/test.scss */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* line 11, ../sass/test.scss */
.a {
  background-color: #CCF;
}

/* line 14, ../sass/test.scss */
.b {
  background-color: #CFC;
}

/* line 17, ../sass/test.scss */
.c {
  background-color: #FCC;
}

/*  GRID OF THREE           ============================================================================= */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* line 24, ../sass/test.scss */
  .span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 28, ../sass/test.scss */
  .span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.1%;
  }

  /* line 32, ../sass/test.scss */
  .span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.2%;
  }

  /*  COLUMN SETUP  */
  /* line 37, ../sass/test.scss */
  .col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
  }

  /* line 42, ../sass/test.scss */
  .col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* line 48, ../sass/test.scss */
  .section {
    width: 100%; /* fix for Firefox */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  /* line 53, ../sass/test.scss */
  .a {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-flex-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }

  /* line 57, ../sass/test.scss */
  .b {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-flex-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}


<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 a">This is column 1</div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 b">This is column 2</div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 c">This is column 3</div>
</div>
```

Note that I've modified your media queries to be a little more efficient.

Comment: Wow, thats is very dam clean! And your doing it without JS which im quite happy with because so far for my entire build i've been using pure html5 & css3 to keep it lightweight. Excellent stuff Cimmanon!

Comment: One thing i dont understand is that "/sass/test.scss" is that only there for reference or does it do something?

Comment: It's just there for debugging with Sass and I was too lazy to cut all of them out when I did the paste.

Comment: I have a problem now. I've jumped in and started populating it with content and its not working now. Its starting to move to the wrong positions and content is overlapping

Comment: Hi @cimmanon this is great. I'm wondering if I could use code similar to this to reorganize table columns on smaller screens? i've tried several different ways to no avail, would love to get your insight on my question here (has a plnkr example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264308/move-table-columns-down-on-smaller-screens

Comment: +1 tvm, 4 years on. Tiny tiny correction to the @media width settings - both can't be 480px. 
Set max-width value to 1px less than min-width value. 
e.g. (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:479px)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a little bit of trouble making sense of your column ordering, but the way to make them rearrange on mobile is to 'push' and 'pull' using margins. For example:

```
.span_1_of_3 {
    margin-left: 33%;
}

.span_2_of_3 {
    margin-left: -65%;
}
```

This will make column 2 appear before column 1 in a side-by-side (desktop) layout, and you can then remove the margins for the stacked (mobile) layout.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KUUt/

**EDIT 2**

I think I've got it set up in the order you wanted. If you're still looking for a solution, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4KUUt/5/

Comment: Thats looking good but i tried ordering it myself and i cant get my head around it. The layout YOU MADE, i need it ordered as "3 moved to 2........
2 moved to 1.......
1 moved to 3.

Any chance you can spare another few minutes to rearrange it?

Comment: @Exhausted - So assuming that on desktop it's (left to right) 1, 2, 3, you want mobile to be 2, 3, 1?

Comment: desktop is 1,2,3 and on mobile i need 1,3,2

Comment: yea sorry you are correct 3,1,2! this is cabbaging my brain! haha

Comment: because, i've just created solution for 3,1,2 and when I saw "1,3,2" my brain exploded :D

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! Thank you so much Miljan! You are a CSS God! :D

Comment: @Exhausted found a (possibly) better way to do it with only css; see my edited answer. This might not be as flexible if you want to rearrange columns in the future, but it's probably more reliable for the grid you're using now.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a bad idea for layout, since it removes those elements from the flow of the document.

Comment: And because of that, I've used jQuery for support :) I didn't know of all those CSS3 properties you've used, @cimmanon.

Comment: @cimmanon Yeah, I'm not a fan of it either. I usually just use Zurb Foundation or 960gs for grids to avoid this kind of thing, but it's fun to try it by hand every once in awhile...

Answer (score 0):

Huh, this is some weird solution, but with jQuery :) Just experimenting.

First, I've added extra classes inside HTML markup. Then, I've added for mobile this properties for class `.third`

```
.third {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

and latter this jQuery code

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(".third").css("position") == "absolute") 
    {
        $(".first").css("margin-top", $(".third").height());
    }
    else
    {
        $(".first").css("margin-top", "1%");
    }
});
```

There is a lot changes, so just take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AYcVF/2/

Maybe someone have CSS only solution, but this is best I can do so far.