# Prioritize center div in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, web

So I have a responsive website set up with three columns, we can call the A, B, C, where A is the main content and B and C is the sidebars.

So I want column A to be centered in between sidebar B and C, but in mobile view, I want A to be prioritized first, with the sidebars at the end. I'm guessing it is somehow done with floats, but I haven't quite figured out how to pull it off smoothly. Apologies if this has been asked before, or should be common knowledge ;)

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 Column Responsive CSS (Ordering Contents Positions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724698/3-column-responsive-css-ordering-contents-positions)

Comment: Well, for my own sake, the thread linked to above solved my problem, and caused a d'oh moment, as I'm using a wp-theme based on Foundation. So I can push and pull the grid. The Q can remain standing if the answer could be helpful to someone else, and to see if its possible with easy html/css. Thank you!