# Flexbox not switching from Row to Column on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to get Flexbox to work on mobile devices, specfically an iPhone 5.  My goal is to have 3 items span across the page on larger screens like iPad and computer monitor and in a column on a mobile device.  I've used code produced by user Cimmanon: [3 Column Responsive CSS (Ordering Contents Positions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724698/3-column-responsive-css-ordering-contents-positions) to get as close as I can.  I'm a long experienced developer (mostly database work) but a relative newbie to Web development and am frustrated by my lack of success.

I'm using Dreamweaver CC to code in.  When I use the CSS below, my page appears as I think it should and when I upload and test in Chrome, IE, and Firefox, I'm getting the results I expect: 3 items across when the browser window is wide and a column with 3 items when the window is narrow.  However, when I use my iPhone, I continue to get the row with 3 items when what I'm wanting to get is the column.

I've now spent many hours on this and would appreciate any help anyone could pass along.  Thanks in advance.

```
/*** FLEXBOX ***************************************/
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.a {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.b {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.c {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;

}

/*  GRID OF THREE           ============================================================================= */
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.1%;
  }

  .span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.2%;
  }

  /*  COLUMN SETUP  */
  .col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
  }

  .col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {


  .section {

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; /* fix for Firefox */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .a {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-flex-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }

  .b {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-flex-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }

  .c {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-flex-order: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Are you using the viewport tag as well (goes inside the head element)?  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Should also mention that IE Mobile supports [`@viewport` rules](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/love-your-devices-adaptive-web-design-with-media-queries-viewport-and-more/) with the ms prefix rather than the viewport tag.

Comment: Awesome.  I was hoping that when I was shining the Cimmanon Bat Signal on the clouds that you'd see it and answer the call.  I've added the line of code you had in your first comment and everything is all roses now.  It's now working in Safari and Chrome on my iPhone 5.  However, I don't have a MS Mobile device to test.  I've added the following lines in CSS
`@-ms-viewport {width: device-width;}`
`@-o-viewport {width: device-width;}`
`@-viewport {width: device-width;}`
The new CSS code for Opera is testing correctly.  Thank you so much Cimmanon!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 media queries not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

Other then written in many blogs, mobile OSses like iOS do not support the flex orientation yet:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Comment: You are incorrect. Flex orientation is supported for each respective webkit-box/-webkit-flexbox/flex specs since Safari 3.0 and iOS 1.0. It's written in the actual link you posted.